# Looking for an elegant way to get ±1-sequence in processing

Tags: processing

I need an alternate sequence like 1, -1, 1, -1... asf. First I used if-statements for it, but it's dumb. Then I tried something like:

```java
int n = 1;
...
do{
   n = 0 + ( n * (-1));
} while(blabla)
```

It's ok, but I have to store n value from iteration to iteration. This isn't so pretty. How to compute that sequence from a control variable like *frameCount*?

Sorry, I am learning not only to code, but English too.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at Processing, but I'll give it a shot. I'm guessing frameCount just increments with every frame? If that's so you could say `n = (frameCount % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1` That is, when frameCount is even, n is 1; when frameCount is odd, n is -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very readable, but if you're looking for something purely "elegant," I suppose you could do something like:

```
int n = 1 - ((frameCount % 2) * 2);
```

If you're on an even frame you'll be subtracting (1 - 0), if you're on odd frame you'll be subtracting (1 - 2).

Answer (score 1):

For readability, I recommend:

`int n = (frameCount & 1) == 1 ? 1 : -1;`

or

```
int n = -1;
if ((frameCount & 1) == 1) {
    n = 1;
}
```

(Note that `x & 1` extracts the lowest bit from `x` just like `x % 2` does.)

Comment: Also note that once a compiler hits it, jffrynpmr's solution is likely going to be faster for machine execution since it has no branching and simple operations.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this

```
float n = 1 ;

void setup() {
....
}

void draw() { 
....
n =-n;
....
}
```

Comment: Because you are using a global state variable, which should be avoided to largest possible extent. Pass the state as a reference or pointer instead.

Answer (score 1):

I recently saw another fun way to create such a sequence using XOR magic.

```
int n = -1, t = 1 ^ -1;
...
do{
   n ^= t;
}while(blabla);
```

Found in [Algorithms for programmers](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtbook.pdf), page 5.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is

```
((framecount & 1)<<1) -1;
```

On even frames, framecount & 1 will yield 0, and the result will then be -1. On odd frames, framecount & 1 will yield 1, and the result will be 1.

Or, less immediate but possibly much faster on some architectures,

```
frameCount-(frameCount^1)
```

When frameCount is odd, frameCount^1 will be equal to frameCount-1, and the result will then be 1. If frameCount is even, frameCount^1 will be equal to frameCount+1, giving -1.